# Framerate issue on galaxy nexus

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm working on my first android game. It involves drawing lines, bitmaps, rectangles, and text to a canvas. On my phone (HTC G2), I get 58-60fps constantly. I had 3 Galaxy Nexus users try the app. One reported 55-60fps and the other two only saw about 30fps.

My question is: What could cause such a huge difference in framerate, especially when the Nexus is a fast phone? Toggling "Force GPU Rendering" did nothing. Also, I don't think the high resolution is to blame because the app runs at a smooth 60fps on my tablet.

Comment: Generally speaking, the chipsets in tablets are much more powerful than in phones. Just because it runs fine on your tablet doesn't mean that the high resolution isn't to blame. (It doesn't sound like this is the case here though since it works fine on one user's device.)